# Problem generating large PDF files with pdfpages

Tags: xetex, pdfpages, latexmk

Using xelatex, I generate a large PDF file (in terms of size and number of pages) by combining a quite high number of files with pdfpages plus other text in Latex. It takes considerable time to generate the file each time I make changes and besides I have to run xelatex multiple times until all the references and TOC entries are correctly resolved and updated. Therefore, I looked at "latexmk -xelated myfile" as a possible solution to ease the process, but sometimes I get an error when latexmk converts itself the xdv file into a pdf file (this is strange because the error is not shown if I manually convert the xdv file to a pdf file myself by calling  xdvipdfmx myself). Maybe it is a temporary random error, but it is quite annoying as I have to re-start the process afterwards, and this is time consuming.

-Any ideas about why this may happen?
-Are there better alternatives than latexmk? (I considered rubber, but it does not seem to work in Windows).

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: To understand what is happening, we'll need to see more details.  Show the output from latexmk including the error message from xdvipdfmx (and its context).

Comment: Usual error:
Can't spawn "xdvipdfmx -o "myfile.pdf"  "myfile.xdv"": No error at c:\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl line 8722.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  xdvipdfmx: Command for 'xdvipdfmx' gave return code 65280
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:790: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -xelatex myfile

Comment: As I commented before, sometimes the PDF file is generated and sometimes there is an error, so the error does not always arise.

Besides, I sometimes get messages such as: "xdvipdfmx:warning: Cannot parse document. Broken PDF file? xdvipdfmx:warning: pdf: image inclusion failed for..." , "xdvipdfmx:warning: Could not find image resource... xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting special command image (pdf:) failed." However, these seem to be warnings, as I can see the final PDF file generated even when these messages appear.

I also tried with the -f option, with similar results.

Comment: @user173026 Could you contact me directly, at the e-mail address in the latexmk documentation. There are too many possibilities, some quite exotic, to be easily sorted out in comments.